Proof verification: $\limsup x_n>b $ iff there exists a subsequence $x_{nk}$ such that $x_{nk}>b, \forall k$.
Prove $\limsup x_n>b $ iff there exists a subsequence $x_{nk}$ such that $x_{nk}>b, \forall k$.
$\longrightarrow$
By definition, we know $\forall k \geq 1, \sup _{n \geq k}x_n >b$, so for $k=1$, we can choose $x_{n_1}>b$, for $k=2$, we can choose $x_{n_2}>b$, but how can we guarantee $n_1 <n_2$?
What if I define in this way? we know $\forall k \geq 1, \sup _{n \geq k}x_n >b$, so for $k=1$, we can choose $x_{n_1}>b$. for $k=n_1+1$, we can choose $x_{n_2}>b$ and so on.
$\longleftarrow$
Suppose there exists a subsequence with the property, then $\sup_{n \geq m} x_n>= \sup_{n \geq m} x_{nk} >b$, so does the limit .

first bit fine, though I don't think the reverse implication is true. For example if $x_n = 1/n$, then $\limsup_n x_n = 0$, yet $x_n > 0$ for all $n$ (which should have meant $\limsup_n x_n > 0$, were this theorem true). If there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x_{n k} > b + \epsilon$, this should be true though, you basically want to eliminate the possibility that $x_{n k} \to b$ or similar

So my proof in the first part is right and for the reverse part, the problem is $an > bn$ does not preserve by taking the limits?

yes, $a_n > b_n$ implies that $\lim_n a_n \ge \lim_n b_n$ not $\lim_n a_n > \lim_n b_n$, equally if you swap the $\lim$ for $\limsup$ or $\liminf$

What if I change $>b$ to $\geq b$? I mean $\limsup x_n \geq b $ iff there exists a subsequence $x_{nk}$ such that $x_{nk} \geq b, \forall k$. Now the reverse part is true but I can not show the other direction.
